# Simpler english by pronunciation

Tags: speech, indirect-speech

I'm into computer science. My question is more relevant to making computers "understand" english. However, I would like to make english simpler, even for/by pronunciation.

It may sound... redundant/weird/strange but does anyone know of any existing forms of "simpler english" that is aimed for people who may have learning disabilities or to educate... computers?

Sounds silly I know... but let's say there's a robot/ai that I would like to teach in its simplest form... I would do this to save disk space and learning time (for the machine).

e.g. 
English:
I have a dream which requires me to learn an old language in a new way.

Simplenglish:
I hef a drim wich requir mi T learn an O language N a neu way.

Saving some character storage space and increase pronunciation effectiveness, all of which can be mapped against the proper English in a hash table form.

Does anyone know of such kind of "simple" english developed? Other than txting.

Comment: I think you are on the wrong path.  spelling and pronunciation are not what makes English hard for computers to learn.

Comment: Well, you could find some of Noah Webster's suggestions that weren't accepted, but I'm not sure if they are simpler (there must be a reason why they didn't catch on). Anyway, I agree with Jim.

Comment: Agreed with @Jim, and it seems you should find the solution in other places. I think it's something related to **Natural Language Processing** and **Machine Learning** that are off-topic here.

Comment: http://espeak.sourceforge.net/phonemes.html Are you looking to create phoneme codes that can be pronounced more easily than English writing?  Or are you trying to create a list of phonemes from samples of English writing?

Comment: I'm looking for "Basic English" by Ogden. The rationale fits what I'm looking for comfortably, though not perfectly. Looking for more alternatives to such "English". Regarding machine learning languages, there was an article long ago that mentioned Sanskrit as the perfect natural fit for AI language... However I wish to use English... the "simple version". Any recommendations or comments regarding alternatives are greatly appreciated. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Basic English doesn't work. There are controlled Englishes for different purposes that are computer-manipulable. Boeing's been writing all their tech docs in AECMA Simplified English for decades; it's saved them millions in translation fees. [Details starting about p.220 in the first article here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/book-7.pdf).

Comment: FYI - John's AECMA is a download thing. @JohnLawler - Is it possible to have a look at AECMA online, Professor?

Comment: Description in the paper. And just the other day somebody told me the style checker was available now. The style checker actually checks style to conform to the AECMA standards; the Boeing tech writers were said to love it.

Comment: This site is about English, a Germanic language. This question keeps talking about english, the spin on a ball in billiards. As such it is off-topic.

Comment: "Saving some character storage space" -- The amount of space one might save with something like this is trivial -- In a medium-complexity natural language processor I suspect it would be less than the space needed to store your average [cat video](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10106555386434970&set=a.10100298019029410.2974873.13965025&type=1).

Comment: Just for grins, you might check out [Es[eranto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto) and other ["universal languages"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_language).  These may give you some hints as to features you'd like.

Comment: I'd begin with never using 'C'

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Basic English created by [Ogden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Kay_Ogden):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_english

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. It's a great "tool". Any alternatives you know of? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately  I have no other suggestions. Though the topic of machine-readable language would interest me. I hope that John Lawler's AECMA English can get you further along. I had a look at Japanese which gives me the idea that it must be possibe to encode the sentence parts with numbers.  And  decades ago I had the idea to replace the conjugation system  with one base form  and indicate tenses, persons, active, passive etc with letters and numbers before and after the verb. But I didn't develop those ideas because I didn't have a need for such things.

Comment: @Samwongdotcom - By googling I found something interesting https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_English  This article is in German, you have to translate it. Obviously the European industry has been using a system similar to Aecma for years.